# PageAsyncTask in webforms button click never executes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, webforms

I need to execute an async operation from a asp.net webforms button click event handler. I've read the documentation [Using Asynchronous Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) and [What not to do in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#asyncevents). The first documentation link shows the `PageAsyncTask` in the `Page_Load` and doesn't cover events like click events. The second documentation link covers my situation.

- My webform is declared as `Async="true"`.
- My web.config http runtime is set to dotnet 4.5 `httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"`

This is my button click event handler:

```cs
protected void DoAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This line executes
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async () =>
    {
        // This line never executes
        var stringToRead = "This line never executes";

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringToRead))
        {
            var readText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Result.Text = readText;
        }
    }));
    
    // This line executes
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(_someUrl, true);
}
```

My issue is that the code inside the `PageAsyncTask` task never executes. I've tried adding `Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();` after registering the task, but it still doesn't execute.

I've also tried making the event handler async void (not recommended) and awaiting the async operation in the conventional async/await pattern. This results in ThreadAbortedExceptions and isn't the recommended approach for webforms anyway.

Comment: Try placing the entire execution within a Task.Run() construct:
var t = Task.Run(() => {...})
t.Wait();

Comment: That would solve it, but it would also block the thread, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What is the point of doing this asynchronously if you're unconditionally redirecting?

Comment: The example isn’t real code, it’s just an example. The real code has several database operations. The point is to not block the thread waiting for long running operations to complete. The async code was not the question, the question was why it was not executed.

Answer (score 3):

I was misunderstanding when the `PageAsyncTask` would be executed. The issue was the redirect after the `Page.RegisterAsyncTask`. The redirect was executed before the `PageAsyncTask`.

Placing the redirect inside the `PageAsyncTask` solves this.

```cs
protected void DoAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async () =>
    {
        var stringToRead = "This line never executes";

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringToRead))
        {
            var readText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Result.Text = readText;
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(_someUrl, true);
    }));
}
```

Comment: if you have a await in your code behind, then you just waiting anyway, and you don't need the async read of the file. That page can't wait with code behind. If the task was to take 30 seconds, then your code behind can start a async task, but the web page and code behind can NOT wait. Web page has to travel back down to client side round trip. If process will finish (say 30 seconds later), then your problem is at that point the async task can't update the web page that is already sitting on the client side browser.  To update you would need a js timer + ajax call and check some session() value

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the reason for this is not about waiting, it's about not blocking threads. If I put synchronous long running tasks in the button click then the thread is blocked while that runs. If it's async then that thread can be used elsewhere while the operation completes. You're correct about AJAX - that would be an alternative solution. My main concern here was why the PageAsyncTask wasn't running, rather than conceptual/architectural issues.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();` immediately after the RegisterAsyncTask call?  I was surprised this worked for you.  I was searching for a snippet that invoked async code inside a command button OnClick event, for a legacy app that is not worth porting to MVC, and this looks promising.